# Issue in Adding Cursor Values to ArrayList

Tags: android

I am trying to query the default phone content provider's Phone Numbers and storing the values thus obtained into an ArrayList
ar = new ArrayList();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

```
    if (cur.getCount() > 0){

        while (cur.getCount() > 0){
            while(cur.moveToNext()){
                //unique id
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                //number corresponding to the id
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                //lets check if this guy even has a number saved
                if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){
                    //Query here
                    //Get the phone numbers!
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{id},null);
                    while(pCur.moveToNext()){
                        ar.add((pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))));
                        }
                    Log.d("String Report", ar.get(5));
                    pCur.close();
                }
```

However this gives array out of bounds error at the Log.d method. For some reason only one value is getting stored insidei.e. I only get ar.get(0) as a valid output. What mistake am i making??

Answer (score 0):

After

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

you have to do

```
cur.moveToNext();
```

And also

```
pCur.moveToNext();
```

before trying to using it!

This to move cursor to first element

Comment: I have already done that in fact ive put pCur.moveToNext in a while loop to get different numbers from the content provider which works as well. However on using it with an ArrayList the arraylist isnt adding values as it should.Why?

Comment: Try to use `pCur.getCount()` inside a Log.d to see how many elements are in your cursor.